# EOS Pubkey to Addresses Conversion

Tags: blockchains

I have few Public Keys for EOS and I want to generate Address from them. I was not able to find the conversion code. Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

EOS blockchain allows to use one public/private key pair for multiple accounts, so it is not really possible to generate address from them.

If you want to find accounts, which use certain public key, Hyperion provides [API](https://hyperion.docs.eosrio.io/api/v2/#v2stateget_key_accounts) to do that.